# Inline script violates Content Security Policy

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I am loading an external script from chargebee.com and I am receiving this error message in console:

> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'nonce-VVZ+V0c=' 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com
>   https://domain.chargebeestatic.com
>   http://dgkxwewtzsnml.cloudfront.net/static/app-static-assets/hp/hp-4.8.5/".
>   Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sjZUY='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

My content security policy defined in Nginx is:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" always;
```

Since I have specified `'unsafe-inline'`, I am not sure why this error pops up.

Update:

I can see when I click on iframe connector in Safari Console:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

<script  nonce="Au5oDesccjEDNeeHfk=" >window.cb_hp_cdn_path="//dgkxetzsnml.cloudfront.net/static/app-static-assets/hp/hp-4.8.5/"</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script  src="https://domain.chargebeestatic.com/api/internal/15346543/retrieve_init_info"  nonce="Au5oejEDNGKHHfk=" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//dgkxwewtzsnml.cloudfront.net/static/app-static-assets/hp/hp-4.8.5/javascripts/vendor.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//dgkxwewtzsnml.cloudfront.net/static/app-static-assets/hp/hp-4.8.5/javascripts/hp_connector.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the actual headers of the response and check the document itself to see if it has an `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="…'">` element. Because either some other part the backend is already setting a Content-Security-Policy header, or the document itself is — and the policy getting set includes `script-src 'nonce-VVZ+V0c=' 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://domain.chargebeestatic.com http://dgkxwewtzsnml.cloudfront.net/static/app-static-assets/hp/hp-4.8.5/"`.

Comment: Please see question update, are the cloudfront assets loaded without https? could  this be  the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You may not use `unsafe-inline` and nonces at the same time. As soon as a nonce is added to your CSP, the `unsafe-inline` directive will be ignored by the browser.

If you're not adding the nonce yourself, then you're not in full control of your CSP because one of your dependencies is adding one which is either merged with yours or worse overwrites yours. Look at your headers with the browser dev tools to see if the headers actually sent correspond with your own CSP. You will find that they don't.

As a matter of fact, using `unsafe-inline` as a script source negates the whole point of having a CSP in the first place, so the best way to solve this would be to refactor your software to use nonces as well and then add your own nonce to your CSP.

Comment: Getting the same problem with onload event listioner, and tried many things, but i see no workaround or change of way to write it, to still perform event listioner like document.onload without it being blocked as "inline". any suggestions?